# "Musical Chairs" between 3 integers

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple game just like Musical Chairs that will loop N times and switch between the values of `a`, `b`, `c` until the loop is ended. I don't know how to implement it. I can guess that I need temporary variables to save the value of each variable in order to switch between them without any corruptions in between.

*Expected Output*

```
N = 1 // Number of times to loop
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 // initialization

a = 3, b = 1, c = 2 // After one loop
```

*This is what I have for now*

```cs
// ...
public static void Main()
{
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
static void MusicalChairs(int N, int a, int b, int c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a = b; b = c;
}
```

Comment: *"I can guess that I need to temporary save the value of each variable in order to swithc between them without any corruptions in between."* Yes. However, you should seriously consider using an array instead. That way, you *still* need a temporary variable, but your life will be made way easier if you ever decide to loop between 100 values instead of only 3.

Comment: Oh, and your code is a prime example of why you should always use braces around blocks: Your `for` block currently only includes `a = b;`, not `b = c;`!

Comment: Not to mention that declaring the variables in one statement *and* initializing them with parse(read()) is going to be difficult to debug. As a general rule, declare one variable per line/statement at the point where it's needed (no sooner) and initialize it at that point.

Comment: will the order of your three persons always stay the same or can one overtake one another?

Comment: @HimBromBeere What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Queue<int>`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var items = new Queue<int>(new int[] {a, b, c});
    MusicalChairs(1, items); 
    Console.WriteLine(items.AsString());  
}

public static void MusicalChairs(int N, Queue<int> items)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
         var item = items.Dequeue();
         items.Enqueue(item);   
    }
}

public static string AsString(this Queue<int> items)
{
   return "(" + string.Join("," items) + ")";
}
```

This rotates the opposite direction from the sample in the question. After one cycle you get `(2,3,1)` instead of `(3,1,2)`. But I suspect 1) the rotation order isn't actually important and 2) if it is you can adjust by reversing the insert and display orders.

Comment: Now that's elegant!

Comment: Hey. I prefer not to do that with `Queue` because I don't know it yet. Can you answer my question using loops? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per Heinzl's comment you'd probably be better off implementing this using an array. It then means the modulo operator could be used to cycle round and round the array:

```
var chairs = new int[3];

//number the chairs
for(int i = 1; i <= chairs.Length; i++)
  chairs[i-1] = i;

int numLoops = 1;

//where should we start printing chairs from?
int offset = chairs.Length - (numLoops%chairs.Length);
    
//print the chairs
for(int i = 0; i < chairs.Length; i++){
  int which = (i + offset)%chairs.Length;
  Console.WriteLine(chairs[which]);
}
```

I see madreflection's come to the same conclusion I did; that you can conceptually move the people/move where you start printing the chairs out from rather than moving the chairs constantly so that the first chair is a different number

After 1 loop its like the end chair is brought to the start, so it's 3, 1, 2. If your loop ran twice it's 2, 3, 1..

If instead we change things up so that for a "one loop round" we start printing the chairs from `Length-1` (the 1 being the number of loops) then we'll print `3,1,2` - the only thing we need to do is have a way of wrapping round to the start if we fall off the end (i.e. to print chair 1 after we just printed chair 3). That can be done with an `if` or with a modulo - `x%y` results in a number between `0` and `y-1` so any number mod by an array's length means that the resulting number must be an index within the array.. So an array of length 10, with an index of 10, when mod by 10 is 0, so this achieves the wrap around

So, we have a chair printing loop that runs 3 times (3 elements in the array), and `i` goes from 0 to 2. We've calculated that we should offset every number by 2 (we start from i=0, plus offset 2, so we start from 2 which will print chair "3")
The next time the loop goes round i is 1, offset is still 2, this would be 3 which is outside the end of the array, but we mod that 3 by 3, 3%3 is 0, so the first element of the array gets printed. This is chair "1". The final loop prints chair "2" in the same way

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this answer as I saw there was already one posted. Since this might help the OP see another possible way to view the question, I'll go ahead and post it. The main thing I want to point out to the OP is that a method can reference an array that it is pointed at and modify the array. The method does not need to have a 'return' value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Shuffle(ref array);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {array[i]}");
    }
            
}

public static void Shuffle(ref int[] array)
{
    if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var last = array.Last();

    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    array[0] = last;
}
```

Comment: Since you don't reassign `array` (you just modify its contents), I'm pretty sure that you don't need `ref` here.

Comment: *face palm* you're right. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. One thing here isn't good for me. I want to pass `N` to `Shuffle`. `N` represent the number of loops to do. Look at the example in my question.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to add it as a parameter?